# Sequentially usage in loop

Tags: bash, adb, wait

I would like to run some adb command in loop. But when I run it like below, my problem is MyActivity have about 15 min duration. I would like to start each job immediately after the previous job starts. With below script each job completes before the next starts. How I could force wait and run them in parallel?

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while [ $i -lt 10 ]; do
  adb shell am start com.package/app.MyActivity
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your commands in the background with `&`:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    adb shell am start com.package/app.MyActivity &
done
```

You might want to add a `sleep 1` or so command inside the loop in case `adb` doesn't like having too many things start at once.